# How to protect to automatic add </div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript code which generates a content:

```
$('#results-list').append('<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-' + i + '">' + '<span class="label label-primary">Further details</span>');
if (item._source.SenderID != null) {
    $('#results-list').append('<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender ID: ' + item._source.SenderID + '</p>');
}
if (item._source.SenderName != null) {
    $('#results-list').append('<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender: ' + item._source.SenderName + '</p>');
}
if (item._source.ReceiverID != null) {
    $('#results-list').append('<p class="list-group-item-text">Receiver ID: ' + item._source.ReceiverID + '</p>');
}
$('#results-list').append('<hr>' + '</div></div>');
```

But it automatically generates this HTML:

```
<div style="" aria-expanded="true" class="collapse in" id="collapseExample-1">
    <div class="well">
        <span class="label label-primary">Further details</span>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender ID: senderTEST:ZZZ</p>
<p class="list-group-item-text">Receiver ID: receiverTEST:ZZZ</p>
```

How to avoid that creating `</div></div>` before the `<p>` segments?

Comment: whats the issue with those closing div tags `</div>` ?

Comment: It seems like you need to edit your question to include the code that's calling this block of JS, because as it's presented here, it doesn't look to me that it would produce the output you show. Does it get called more than once? Where does the `<div class="well">` from from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add whole elements to the DOM, not an opening or closing tag at a time. You need to build the HTML in a string first, then append it. Try this:

```
var html = '<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-' + i + '"><span class="label label-primary">Further details</span>';

if (item._source.SenderID != null)
    html += '<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender ID: ' + item._source.SenderID + '</p>';

if (item._source.SenderName != null)
    html += '<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender: ' + item._source.SenderName + '</p>';

if (item._source.ReceiverID != null)
    html += '<p class="list-group-item-text">Receiver ID: ' + item._source.ReceiverID + '</p>';

html += '</div><hr />';
$('#results-list').append(html);
```

Comment: This helped the most. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create complete div using jQuery, then append it to `#results-list` element

```
var div = $('<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-' + i + '"><span class="label label-primary">Further details</span></div>');
if (item._source.SenderID != null) {
    div.append('<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender ID: ' + item._source.SenderID + '</p>');
}
if (item._source.SenderName != null) {
    div.append('<p class="list-group-item-text">Sender: ' + item._source.SenderName + '</p>');
}
if (item._source.ReceiverID != null) {
    div.append('<p class="list-group-item-text">Receiver ID: ' + item._source.ReceiverID + '</p>');
}
div.append('<hr>').appendTo('#results-list');
```